# Recent Update crashed Unity and Window manager

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz

I just updated a few packages. Among them was the ubuntu-desktop package (maybe it has something to do with that). After the update the Unity Launcher no longer stacks Items, so I have to scroll. Additionally the grid system (moving a window to the top, left or right of a screen to maximize it) does not work anymore. Starting Unity from a console gives back

```
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1a00004

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1400002

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x140000c

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1200002

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x1200047

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x4600003

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x40000b8

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing fade options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Initializing scale options...done

(compiz:3060): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
compiz (unityshell) - Error: GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object not supported

X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  33 (X_GrabKey)
  Serial number of failed request:  7120
  Current serial number in output stream:  7366
```

I have an ATI Card with the newest Catalyst drivers installed. If I can provide any more information for someone to help me, please ask.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling of the fglrx drivers worked for me. Thankst